# Trying to parse through html data

Tags: python, html

window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"a32f4d9af8","applicationID":"1098263064","transactionName":"ZVABZEMDChJTWkcLWFwaImNhTQETQFZBPUdTUgZDHgcWE11LHlYHBhsCQ0Ea","queueTime":1,"applicationTime":11,"agent":"","atts":""}(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).init={ajax:{deny_list:["bam.nr-data.net"]}};(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={licenseKey:"a32f4d9af8",applicationID:"1098263064"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var i=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(i.exports,function(e){var i=t[n][1][e];return r(i||e)},i,i.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var i=0;i0){var r=n[n.length-1];if(u&&uv.offset&&e

Comment: was able to get the data pulled but can't figure out to how correctly parse the information. I just need the ACTIVE accounts listen in the html but it's in the ng-binding angular JS

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If this is in javascript:

Store the object in a variable and access them through a bracket or dot notation. For instance, console.log(NREUM.info["beacon"]) will return the value, "bam.nr-data.net".